# Rotation of triangle interfering with axis color

Tags: manipulate

I'm trying to demonstrate an interesting problem in geometry:  Rotate the red triangle -Pi/3 but when it hits the x-axis, the red line segment disappears apparently behind the black color of the axis.  I was wondering if someone could help me demonstrate this so that the red leg of the triangle remains even when it's superimposed over the black axis?

Thanks for reading,
Dominic

```
thef[x_] := 1/2 (Sqrt[3] - 2 Sqrt[1 - 2 x])
p1 = Plot[thef[x], {x, 0, 1}];
point1 = Graphics[{Red, Point[{0.3, thef[0.3]}]}];
Clear[myTransform, myRotatedPoint]
triangle2 = 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], 
    Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.3, thef[0.3]}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]}];
r = RotationTransform[theta]
r[{0, 1/2}] /. theta -> -Pi/4
myRotatedPoint[myVal_] := r[{0.3, thef[0.3]}] /. theta -> myVal;

myRotatedPointGraphics[myVal_] := 
  Graphics[{Red, Point@myRotatedPoint[myVal]}];
myRotatedLineGraphics[myVal_] := 
  Graphics[Line[{{0.3, thef[0.3]}, myRotatedPoint[myVal]}]];
thirdLine = Graphics[Line[{{0.3, thef[0.3]}, {1, 0}}]];

myTransform[myT_] := 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], 
     Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0.3, thef[0.3]}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]}, 
    RotationMatrix[myT]]];
Manipulate[
 Show[{Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], 
     Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]}], triangle2, 
   myTransform[myT], p1, point1, myRotatedPointGraphics[myT], 
   myRotatedLineGraphics[myT], thirdLine}, Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> 1], {myT, 0, -Pi/3}]
```

[image]

Comment: what is `thef`?

Comment: try `EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}]` instead of `EdgeForm[Red]`  when you define `triangle2 `?

Comment: Sorry, forgot def of thef:  thef[x_] := 1/2 (Sqrt[3] - 2 Sqrt[1 - 2 x])  and added to above code.

Comment: Ok, thanks, the {Thick,Red} did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `EdgeForm[Red]` with `EdgeForm[{Thick,Red}]` in the definition of `myTransform`.

[image]

Comment: @Dominic, thank you for the accept. May I suggest you revisit your older questions to see if any answers are worth accepting?

Comment: Ok of course.  Done.  Hadn't been doing that.  Will do in future.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can move axes to the back. Modify the first `Graphics` command inside the `Manipulate` as follows.

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], 
  Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}]}
 , Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}
 ]
```

---

[image]